# How can I get this python program to remember a previous value and add it?

Tags: python, pycharm

[So this is my program so far.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCGY1.jpg)

[This is my outcome.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lYLp.jpg)

[This is what it is supposed to look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rwVg.jpg)

---

This is the context behind the program.

Instructors in a community college are paid on a schedule that provides a salary based on their number of years of teaching experience.  For each year of experience after the first year, up to 10 years, the instructor receives a 2% increase over the preceding value.  Suppose the initial salary of an instructor is $50,000.  In the second year, this instructor’s salary will be $51,000 ($50,000 + $50,000 * 0.02 = $51,000).  In the third year, the salary will be $52,020 ($51,000 + $51,000 * 0.02 = $52,020), and so on.  In addition, the instructor is required to deposit 5% of the salary each year into a retirement fund account.  For example, if the salary is $50,000 in a year, $2500 ($50,000 * 0.05) will be deposited into his/her retirement fund account.  Write a program to do the following.  Ask the user to enter the first year’s salary.  Calculate and display the salary each year in the first 10 years.  Also, calculate and display a running total of the instructor’s retirement fund after each year.

---

Please keep in mind that I am an absolute beginner when it comes to python programming, and programming in general, so I understand that my code is probably not efficient or even the easiest way of doing things.

My problem is not the salary accumulating, but the retirement fund remembering the value before based off of the new salary every year and then adding the amount of money put into the retirement fund plus the former amount of money already in the retirement fund.

Can anyone please help me on how to make the retirement fund add up as the context above wants it to?

Comment: Please post text, not images of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you set

```
new_salary = salary
```

and then update the value of new_salary on each iteration, but never salary, which is what retirement_fund is calculated from on line 13. Change line 13 to use the updated salary instead.